# Composer - Unable to install mongodb/mongodb on Windows

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, composer-php

I'm trying to install the following package on my Laravel installation using composer : `jenssegers/mongodb`

But when installing, I'm getting the following error :

```
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.2 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.0 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2].
```

The extension is actually listed when I run `composer show -p` like that :

```
ext-mongo           1.6.12   The mongo PHP extension
```

and it's also enabled correctly when I do php_info() or anything.

I'm also sure that I enabled it in the correct php.ini file.

Actually, I guess that the problem comes from the fact that it should be called `mongodb` instead of `mongo`.

Is their any fix for this for Windows ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, so it seems like I was installing the old legacy driver which is not supported.

To clarify things up, there's two available drivers for MongoDB for PHP :

- The legacy one, available here : https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo
- The most recent one, available here : https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

The legacy driver will be identified as `mongo` by PHP, while the new one is correctly identified as `mongodb`.

Comment: Are they both needed or just the `mongodb` ?

Comment: @AntoineB could you detail more with it, how i should to do, i got this problem too, i download package ready but don't know how to config it

Comment: @skjulikaka If I remember correctly, I didn't have to do any configuration to mongodb. That said, you have to start the service in order for it to run, but that's not related to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after searching for a while, i can across this solution:

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This ignores all platform requirements and 'force' installs.

Source: [Composer can't find mongodb extension](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/797)